# Listen to onpopstate with Vuejs without vue-router

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am using vue.js with laravel and I am using a vue component with laravel blade file. I want to reload the page when I press the back navigation button to go to the previous page. I have this code for the purpose:

```
created() {
       window.onpopstate = function(event) {
       location.reload();
    };
```

This is not working. I can go back with the back button of the browser and yet there is no reload. How I can achieve the result? Again, I am not using vue-router. I am using laravel's route to load blade file, and the blade file contains the vue file.
The blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
  <vue-component></vue-component>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your problem is that browser persist state on back button. It is a known bug in vue related with chrome based browsers [here is more info about it](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11165#issuecomment-685819170). To solve this without reloading the page you need to init Vue in pageshow event just like this:

```js
const initVue = () => {
    return new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        store
    });
   }
    const app = window.addEventListener('pageshow', () => {
        initVue();
    })
```

But to solve this issue in Safari you must reload the page(Apply it in your master layout blade).

```js
  (function () {
            window.onpageshow = function (event) {
            if (event.persisted) {
                window.location.reload();
                }
            };
        })();
```

Or if you really want to solve this issue by reloading the page when back button is used then u need a method like this for your component or you can use it in you master layout blade to apply it everywhere:

```js
methods: {
    checkBackButton: function() {
            if (
                window.performance &&
                window.performance.navigation.type ===
                    window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD &&
                this.type === "main"
            ) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
},

mounted() {
   this.checkBackButton();
}
```